# Asking for confirmation when "X" button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, button

The problem is that the messagebox with "sure you wanna close?" does pop up, but when I click "no", it still proceeds to close the program. Any suggestions?
Here's my code:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseCancel();
    }

    public static void CloseCancel()
    {
        const string message = "Are you sure that you would like to cancel the installer?";
        const string caption = "Cancel Installer";
        var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                     MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are expected to set the [`Cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property of the `FormClosingEventArgs` argument to `true` when you require the close-operation to be cancelled. And an explicit `Environment.Exit(0)` is *normally* not required since the form is on its way to being closed any way (the cancellation of the shutdown process is opt-in, not opt-out).

Replace the last bit with:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);

e.Cancel = (result == DialogResult.No);
```

Answer (score 8):

e.Cancel on the FormClosing event will stop the closing process

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CloseCancel()==false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        };
    }

    public static bool CloseCancel()
    {
        const string message = "Are you sure that you would like to cancel the installer?";
        const string caption = "Cancel Installer";
        var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                     MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

The question is now old but this way is more simple and short, and I think it can be useful to those who arrive on this page:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you would like to cancel the installer?", "Cancel Installer", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

and use elsewhere `this.Close()` rather than a function.

Comment: This answer is the least complicated, most functional and easiest to follow of all answers currently here.

Answer (score 2):

just take it simple

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {            
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
            if (PreClosingConfirmation() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Dispose(true);
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        private DialogResult PreClosingConfirmation()
        {
            DialogResult res = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" Do you want to quit?          ", "Quit...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            return res;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected Boolean CanClose(Boolean CanIt)
{
   if(MessageBox.Show("Wanna close?", "Cancel Installer", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,       MessageBoxIcon.Question).ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
      // Yes, they want to close.
      CanIt = true;
   }
   else
   {
     // No, they don't want to close.
     CanIt = false;
   }

   return CanIt;
}

protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(CanClose(false) == true)
    {
       this.Dispose(true);
    }
    else
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to handle the other scenario you mentioned (handling the 'X' click). Maybe you could do something like this (psuedo-code):

```
// IF CLICKED YES
   THEN CLOSE
// ELSE-IF CLICKED NO
   THEN DO NOTHING
// ELSE
   THEN DO NOTHING
```

Comment: This is it, but you are overdoing things. Why `CanClose(false)` and not `CanClose()`?

Comment: well tried, you don't need an argument in the CanClose() method, congrats for first answer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private void FormName_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close ?", "CLOSE", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //code to run before close

        }
       
    }
```