# how to confirm the process close in c#

Tags: c#

First See My Code Below

```
private void calculatorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cf == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Process runcalc = Process.Start("calc.exe"))
                    if (runcalc.HasExited)
                    {
                        cf = 0;
                    }
                    else
                        cf = 1;
            }             catch 
        {      
        }
    }
```

What Am I Doing:

I am Calling The Process Calc from Main Form Named(Login)

What I Need:
I Need To Change The int variable value cf = 0 when the Calc is Closed in Process.

What i Am Getting:
the Code runcalc.hasexited is not giving the confirmation of Close of process Calc.

I am Not I need Of Confirmation of Closing the Form 
I needed Confirmation of Closing of Process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking for confirmation when "X" button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367586/asking-for-confirmation-when-x-button-is-clicked)

Comment: There are too many exit confirmation dialog guides to ask it again

Comment: thanks Sir, But i am Asking the Confirmation of Process Close And not of From Close

Comment: Sir @caxapexac Can you Explain Me How to use Dialog result to confirm Closing of process.

Comment: The answer to your question is easily found,  the docs are very clear. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited

Comment: Respected @Menahem But that didn't Worked for Me.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work" for you? the documentation for the `HasExited` property answers your question, (`To ensure that asynchronous event handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload that takes no parameter before checking HasExited.`) My point is , before asking a question try reading the documentation / google for the information first. (i did not down-vote your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to call `runcalc.WaitForExit();` so that your code stops till Calc is finished. If you want to do it asynchronously, you will have to bind to `x.Exited` event.